# Send form and update button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a page where users can vote a post or comment with an empty form. I have written JavaScript to submit the form and update the button with the vote count without refreshing the entire page. Instead of refreshing the button, the JavaScript routes to a new page with the JSON data returned from Flask.

post.html

```
<form class="d-inline" id="vote_form" action="{{ url_for('main.post', id=post.id) }}" method="post">           
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
    <button class="px-1 py-0 btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" id="vote_post_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="vote_post">&#8679; 2</button>
</form>

<form class="d-inline" action="{{ url_for('main.post', id=comment.id) }}" method="post">                    
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
    <button class="px-1 py-0 btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" id="vote_comment_btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="vote_comment">&#8679; 0</button>
</form>
```

routes.py

```
@bp.route('/post/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post(id):
    post = db.first_or_404(sa.select(Post).where(Post.id == id))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit'] == 'vote_post':
            vote = db.session.scalar(sa.select(PostVote).where((PostVote.user_id == current_user.id) & (PostVote.post_id == id)))
            post = db.session.scalar(sa.select(Post).where(Post.id == id))
            if vote is None:
                vote = PostVote(user_id=current_user.id, post_id=id)
                db.session.add(vote)
                db.session.commit()              
                return jsonify({"votes": post.votes_count(), "voted": True})
            else:
                db.session.delete(vote)
                db.session.commit()              
                return jsonify({"votes": post.votes_count(), "voted": False})
        if request.form['submit'] == 'vote_comment':
            vote = db.session.scalar(sa.select(CommentVote).where((CommentVote.user_id == current_user.id) & (CommentVote.comment_id == id)))
            comment = db.session.scalar(sa.select(Comment).where(Comment.id == id))
            if vote is None:
                vote = CommentVote(user_id=current_user.id, comment_id=id)
                db.session.add(vote)
                db.session.commit()
                return jsonify({"votes": comment.votes_count(), "voted": True})
            else:
                db.session.delete(vote)
                db.session.commit()
                return jsonify({"votes": comment.votes_count(), "voted": False})
```

javascript

```
        async function sendVote() {
            let form = document.getElementById("vote_form");            
            let formBtn = document.querySelectorAll("#vote_post_btn, #vote_comment_btn");
            let url = form.getAttribute("action");
                  // Associate the FormData object with the form element
                  const formData = new FormData(form);

                  try {
                    const response = await fetch(url, {
                      method: "POST",
                    })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        formBtn.innerHTML = data["votes"];
                        if (data["votes"] === true) {
                            formBtn.className = "px-1 py-0 btn btn-secondary btn-sm";
                        }
                        else {
                            formBtn.className = "px-1 py-0 btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm";
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(await response.json());
                  } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                  }
        }
        //Take over form submission
        form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          sendVote();
        });
```

page rendered

```
{
  "voted": true,
  "votes": 1
}
```

The JavaScript doesn't update the button class and vote count. It renders JSON on a new page instead.
I used this [MDN Advanced forms article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) and [MDN json method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) to write the javascript.